# Korean text displays as ??? when outputting a column returned through adodb recordset

Tags: adodb, cjk, sql-server-2019

Korean text displays exactly as it should if I run a query in SQL Server Management Studio.

If I run a query with an `adodb.recordset` through an `adodb.connection` (using the `MSOLEDBSQL` provider), when I go to `Response.write(rs("variable"))`, it spits out question marks. Database used is SQL Server 2019.

I can hardcode the same value in the classic ASP file (yeah yeah, I know, I know) and it displays properly.

I first thought it was a table collation issue. I suppose it could still be, but I'm sort of doubting that, now (collation of the table is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`) after tracking this issue for several days online.

The page uses the UTF-8 charset as a meta tag in the head section.

Data is stored in a column of type `nVarChar(4000)`, and was stored using unicode notation:

```
insert into myTable (StringValue) 
values(N'koreantext')
```

But, again, when retrieving that value and writing it out, it displays as question marks. The data appears to have been stored correctly since SQL Server Management Studio displays the query as expected / desired.

Am I missing something obvious? Any help is appreciated.